# android process camera image AFTERwards in OnActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, onactivityresult

Per the Google Android camera tutorial I'm using:

```
new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

or

```
new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

to open the camera in my app.

Unfortunately, this forces the user to decide beforehand and prevents the user from toggling between pic & vid modes.

My problem is I want the user to go directly to the camera, be able to toggle between picture & video mode, 
and then save the image/video accordingly.

Is there some way to:

1) read the Intent data in onActivityResult() and

2) ascertain (***AFTER*** the image has been saved, ***NOT*** before) whether it's a pic or a video,

then

3) rename the image to ".jpg" or ".mp4" accordingly?

I've noticed that when I use

```
new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA);
```

that the camera can then toggle between pic & vid.

But then it won't programmatically save the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the user to go directly to the camera, be able to toggle between picture & video mode, and then save the image/video accordingly.

That is not going to be possible in general, for the simple reason that you are asking *other apps* to take pictures and videos on your behalf. The protocol that Android has established for doing that is via the `Intent` actions that you are presently using. There is no `ACTION_CAPTURE_SOMETHING_THAT_THE_USER_THINKS_IS_COOL` or the equivalent that allows you to express that you want the user to make a choice after starting the third-party camera activity.

> I've noticed that when I use `new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA);`
>   that the camera can then toggle between pic & vid.

Only for the couple of camera apps that you have tried, out of thousands (pre-installed by device manufacturers, downloaded by users from the Play Store, etc.). [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA) certainly would not imply that behavior would be expected of all camera apps.